# Split decimal from text as batch

Tags: excel, split, powerquery

Attempting to split decimal numbers in batch using a prevo=ious formula provided on here however the result is an error stating that null or "" or "x" (where is a number) cant be converted to the type list.

The formula:

`=try Text.Remove([Column1],Text.ToList(Text.Remove([Column1],{"0".."9","."}))) otherwise null` works when applied to a single column however when trying to create a create a table from these columns I get the followings errors:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table19"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.FromColumns({
        
    (try Text.Remove([Column1],Text.ToList(Text.Remove([Column1],{"0".."9","."}))) otherwise null), 
    
    (try Text.Remove([Column2],Text.ToList(Text.Remove([Column2],{"0".."9","."}))) otherwise null)
    
    }))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

I would like to be able to generate a Table.FromColumns, for n columns which I can then expand. This is just an example and in reality, the number of columns can vary quite a lot.

**Update**

To better visualise what I am trying to do in power query I wish to create this scenario:

[image]

Such that this table can be expanded to:

[image]

Probably something obvious but any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just

- split the columns based on character transition, including the decimal in the character list.
- Then `Trim` the resultant columns to remove any leading/following spaces

***Note:** Code edited to allow for any number of columns to be split in two. Column names can be dynamic also*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table21"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

//Generate new table from all the columns
    //create List of columns
        colList = Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type"),
        colNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),

    //convert each column
        splitCols = List.Generate(
            ()=>[colPair=
                    List.Transform(colList{0},(li)=>
                        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition(
                            {"0".."9","."}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9","."}, c))
                            (li)), 
                 cn = colNames{0},
                 idx=0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(colList),
            each [colPair=
                    List.Transform(colList{[idx]+1},(li)=>
                        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition(
                            {"0".."9","."}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9","."}, c))
                            (li)), 
                   cn=colNames{[idx]+1},
                   idx=[idx]+1],
            each  List.Zip([colPair]) & {List.Transform({1..2}, (n)=> [cn] & "." & Text.From(n))}),
    newCols = List.Combine(List.Transform(splitCols, each List.RemoveLastN(_,1))),
    newColNames = List.Combine(List.Transform(splitCols, each List.Last(_))),
    newTable = Table.FromColumns(newCols,newColNames),

//trim the excess spaces
    trimOps = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(newTable), each {_, Text.Trim}),
    trimAll = Table.TransformColumns(newTable, trimOps)
in
    trimAll
```

[image]

***Example with three columns***
[image]

*Again, if you want to retain the original columns in your result table, you need to change three lines in the code:*

```
...
    newCols = Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & List.Combine(List.Transform(splitCols, each List.RemoveLastN(_,1))),
    newColNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & List.Combine(List.Transform(splitCols, each List.Last(_))),
    newTable = Table.FromColumns(newCols,newColNames),
...
```

[image]

Comment: Hi apologies I should have said in the question that I would like to generate a Table from the columns to avoid having multiple steps in the query. I hope to be able to just expand this.

Comment: @Nick Will it always be the case that each single column will be split into two columns?  Or could a single column be split into more than two columns?

Comment: In this case, as its just value and units are always 2. Though I guess to future proof if possible for more columns it would be nice. Im going to try and add an image to better explain.

Comment: @Nick Edited to handle any number of columns, with any column names.  Because of the splitter method, I am still assuming only a two column split for each single column; but if you change the splitting method to allow for a variable number of splitted columns, the algorithm can handle that also with minor changes.

Answer (score 2):

Edited to be usable for multiple columns

```
let Source =Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Value.2"}),
#"rename1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Attribute", each _&"a", type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" =  Table.RemoveColumns(Table.Pivot(#"rename1", List.Distinct(#"Lowercased Text"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value.1"),{"Index"}),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Value.1"}),
rename = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Attribute", each _ & "b", type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column1" = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.Pivot(rename, List.Distinct(rename[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value.2"),{"Index"}),
TFC = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&Table.ToColumns(#"Pivoted Column")&Table.ToColumns(#"Pivoted Column1"),Table.ColumnNames(Source)&Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column")&Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column1"))
in TFC
```

Comment: Hi argh, annoyingly I should have said in the question. Table.FromColumns is because I would like to do this for n columns. This is just an example, In reality, I have 20+ columns and ideally want to avoid having multiple steps. So I was hoping I could have a step which generates a table containing this info which I can then just expand.

Comment: edited for multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

I would just duplicate the two original columns (Add Column > Duplicate column) and then split the resulting columns on the left most " " delimiter.  No M code needed.

[image]